# Proving that if $x$ is a limit point of a sequence, then any interval with midpoint $x$ is a lure.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x$ be a limit point of a sequence {${x_n}$}. Then for any given ϵ that is a positive number and any number $k$, there is an integer $n>k$ such that
$|x_n-a|<ϵ$. Now let us consider the interval $[s,t]$ where $x$ is a midpoint. Then $x-s=t-x$. I am not sure how to proceed from here, or if I even set this up correctly. I know that a lure is an interval with a infinite amount of terms within the interval. I am just not sure how to relate these 2 ideas together.

Comment: I believe you need "non-singleton" interval for the statement to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can suppose the interval is $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. Since $x$ is a limit point there is $N$ so that if $n>N$ we have $|x-x_n|<\epsilon \iff x_n\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. This gives us an infinite number of values of $n$ for which $x_n\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$, proving the interval is a lure.

Comment: Thank you for replying.Is the $a_n$ you are using the same as my $x_n$ or is that different sequence?

Comment: it is the same, let me change t.

Comment: Repeating myself about that technicality: not **every** interval. Only the non-singleton ones, i.e. those with non-empty interior... $[x,x]$ does not work.

Comment: oh yeah ${}{}{}{}{}$